# Cross-origin permissions from chrome-extension:// pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to "proxy" web pages through a chrome-extension:// page (using an full-frame iframe), so that they show up as an extension page, instead of a webpage.  I still want to apply content scripts to them, however, and have not had any success doing this.  Is there a way to allow the chrome-extension page to access the contents of the iframe because it's "privileged" and should be allowed to get around XSS limitations?

Whenever I try to executeScript( { code : blah , allFrames: true }) I get an error about XSS about the chrome-extenion page, not the http page inside it...

Ideas?

Comment: It seems like it's impossible to man-handle (inject, etc.) http:// content that is inside an iframe inside chrome-exension:// - but not just regular http content.  Is this so?  If so, why?

Comment: What pages are you proxying? Is the content safe?

Comment: Our plugin's UI is half server-side, so that's what we're proxying.  So yes, it's safe :D.

Comment: Why do you have to embed your page in a frame? Just open the external page (using [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create), for example), and enhance the page using content scripts. An alternative method is to use `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch data, and build the page in an extension page.

Comment: @RobW - The reason I want it in an extension page is so that the URL doesn't appear in the address bar, do you know of another way to control what appears in the address bar?

Comment: There's no other way. Why do you want to hide the address?