# AJAX calls inside an iframe inside an extension page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that displays UI from a web service as its own inside an iframe inside an extension page.  I am injecting some content scripts into the remote UI using:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches" : [ "https://mywebservice.com/frontend/*" ] ,
    "js" : [ "frontend-page-contentscript.js" ],
    "all_frames" : true
  }
]
```

Which is allowed because of (also in manifest.json):  [EDIT: This turns out NOT to be required to run content-scripts in the iframe - but removing it doesn't make AJAX work the way I expect].

```
"sandbox" : {
  "pages" : [
    "cocoon_page_proxy.html"
  ]
}
```

However, when I make a trivial ajax call (not from the content script, from the iframe):

```
$.get('asdf',function success(data) { console.log("Success"); },
             function error(xhr) { console.log("Error: "+xhr.responseText); });
```

I don't get any response, it stalls out and gets a "0" for a status.  This (in my experience) is usually due to a cross-origin permissions problem, but it shouldn't be - it's requesting another resource from the same server the main page came from.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried doing an ajax call to the same domain? You could even send an ajax call to `chrome.extension.getURL('frontend-page-contentscript.js')` and it should return the contents of that file.

Comment: chrome.extension.getURL generates a url like `chrome-extension://oidssafjkkljreiousfdljk/frontend-page-contentscript.js` where that random string is the extension ID.

Comment: So you have `chrome-extension://` page with an iframe that directly references a remote page in it's `src` attribute? I get the impression that `cocoon_page_proxy.html` is a local page but it's not clear from your description. Why did you have to put that page in a sandbox? You say "Which is allowed..." but you don't say *what* is allowed? You certainly don't need that in order to run a content script on a page.

Comment: @DevinGRhode - Ajax in the context of the top-level page works to the places you would expect.  From inside the iframe, requests to `chrome-extension` URIs do not work, and requests to the host from which the iframe's contents were retrieved also do not work.

Comment: @MatthewGertner - you are correct in your interpretation.  Also,  I confused the "sandbox" feature with a fix of a behavior that prompted an earlier question of mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234772/cross-origin-permissions-from-chrome-extension-pages).  I thought I had to "sandbox" the page in order to allow what I had asked in that question.  Turns out, you don't, and after removing the sandbox the AJAX cross-origin blocking  is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh - it turns out to be a bug stemming from elsewhere in my extension, in webrequest redirect code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand correctly and you are loading a `chrome-extension://` URL into the frame and trying to XHR the contents of the remote page from there, you need to [request cross-origin permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html#requesting-permission) for that domain.

Comment: This is important, and in general probably the cause of this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you can actually force cross domain ajax with the webRequest api in Chrome. You simply add the http header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` onHeadersReceived.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function onHeadersReceived(resp) {
  resp.responseHeaders.forEach(function forEachHeader(header, index) {
    if(header.name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-origin") {
      resp.responseHeaders[index].value = "*";
    }
  });
  resp.responseHeaders[resp.responseHeaders.length] = {
    "name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value":"*"
  };
  return {responseHeaders: resp.responseHeaders};
}, {
  urls: [
  //chrome-extension://jkafskjifsf/cocoon_page_proxy.html
    chrome.extension.getURL('') + 'cocoon_page_proxy.html',
   '*://your.api.endpoint.domain.com/*'
  ] ,
  types: [
    'sub_frame'
  ]
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

Try adding that to your background page. If you don't have a background page, add this to your manifest.json and create the associated file:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
}
```

You'll also need to ADD these items to your existing `permissions` list in the your manifest.json file:

```
//"permissions": [
    "chrome-extension://<put_your_extension_id_here>/cocoon_page_proxy.html",
    "*://your.api.endpoint.domain.com/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
//],
```

For the URLs, like `*://your.api.endpoint.domain.com/*`, add any urls you need to make ajax requests too.

Please comment how this works and if you run into any issues.

Comment: You should mark answer as correct if it was useful, I referenced it again and used it.